# Comma for clause separation or?

Tags: comma

> "Oje, Oje", hat da die Frau gejammert.

I'm trying to figure out the modified word order in this sentence.

Does the comma indicate that "Oje Oje" is considered a subordinate clause preceding the main one thus making "hat" go to the first position?

OR

Is "Oje, Oje" just considered a subject noun and thus the verb is occupying its regular 2nd position?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No to both of your assumptions. Direct speech is neither considered an object (if at all) nor a subordinate clause. It's simply direct speech and thus follows its own rules - It has to be separated from the main clause with quotation marks and commas, and it can take specific positions in the sentence (that are not necessarily aligned with typical subject or object positions), and it can even be split across the sentence.

> "Oje", hat da die Frau gejammert, "Oje"
>
> "Oje, Oje", hat da die Frau gejammert
>
> Da hat die Frau, "Oje, Oje", gejammert
>
> Da hat die Frau gejammert, "Oje, Oje".

All meaning the same thing...

Comment: Then the question might be, "How does "Oje" or "Oje,oje" occupy the first spot in the sentence, pushing the verb (hat) after it. For instance, "doch" or "denn" does not perform this function.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. The main thing is that direct speech must be separated with a comma from the rest of the sentence and occupies a position in the word order, thus coming in the start of a sentence means my verb must go to the second position right?